# CSS transition only effecting li not ul

Tags: css

I've made a pure CSS nav bar from this website.

http://blog.christopherianmurphy.com/2016/01/responsive-pure-css-menu.html

See a crude version here (looks crap, just ignore that)

http://codepen.io/spinnaay/pen/ZOVNwg

It works fine apart from one detail.

When in 'mobile mode' the dropdown menu doesn't transistion, only the text. Basically the ul isn't transistioning but the li is.

If you change

```
nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul {
  height:100%;
}
```

to

```
nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul {
  height:100vh;
}
```

that works but then the menu is too long.

This is a strange problem to me but surely there is a simple answer.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Your "crude version" is where now?

Comment: Yup missed that! Added now.

Answer (score 0):

- height: 100vh -> Means 100% of the viewport height. (browser window)
- height: 100% -> Means 100% of the height of the parent.

To my understanding you can't use transition on a height percentage. But you can use a transition on the min-height property.

Try to add the following to your code:

```
nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul {
  min-height:0;
  transition: min-height .2s ease-in-out;
}

nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul {
  min-height:900px; // number higher then the total size of the children
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do both of these styles go together as they are have matching identifiers. The min height will clash? Thanks for looking.